# Huxreg output doesn't fit pdf created by R Markdown/knitr

Tags: r, regression, r-markdown

I am working in R Markdown and built several regression models and made a summary table with huxreg. The models have a lot of features and, therefore, the summary table is quite big. When I check the output in the code it looks perfectly fine. However, when I "knit" the code to pdf, the table is huge and it fits neither the width nor the height of the pdf page. It is also not prolonged to the next page.

The code:

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, error=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)
setwd('/Users/ladarudnitckaia/Data')
```

pre-processing, training the models, etc.

```
{r, echo=FALSE}
huxtable_glm <- huxreg("glm (inside)"=model1,
       "glm (+lags)"=model2,
       "glm (+outside)"=model3,
       "glm (+lags)"=model4,
       "glm (+indiv.)"=model5,
       "glm (+lags)"=model6,
       "glm (+EDA)"=model7,
       "glm (+lags)"=model8f,
       statistics = c(N = "nobs"),
       stars=NULL,bold_signif=0.05)

huxtable::position(huxtable_glm) <- "left"
huxtable_glm
```

The pdf looks as following:

[pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sByJm.png)

Any suggestions on how to properly fit the table to the pdf (it will hardly fit in 1 page, but 2 are also fine) would be very helpful!

Thank you in advance!

P.s. Stargazer was even worse.

Answer (score 1):

well, took some time, but this helped:

```
huxtable::font_size(huxtable_glm) <- 6
huxtable::guess_knitr_output_format()
huxtable::height(huxtable_glm) <- 1
huxtable::width(huxtable_glm) <- 0.75
huxtable_glm
```

Comment: However, this doesn't always work properly. For example, with my following tables I encountered the problem that, e.g., huxtable::height(huxtable_glm) <- 1 works, but huxtable::font_size(huxtable_glm) <- 6 is ignored. It would be nice to have some function that could just automatically fit the table to the page...

Comment: If you surround the huxtable code with a LaTeX `\resizebox{}`, that might work. Also BTW, you don't need the `guess_...` call there. That's a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to split the table:

In one part of your document:

```
huxtable_glm[1:5, ]
```

Later on

```
huxtable_glm[6:nrow(huxtable_glm), ]
```

Huxtable version 5 has some facilities to make this a little easier: you can use the `split_across()` function which will preserve column headers.